# How to get, save, and reuse scroll position in a WebView in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-webview

I am making a E-book reader application. I am using a WebView to display HTML formatted data coming through jSON.

If a user is reading a book and quits the app in between, I want to get the position of the text so that next time the user continues reading the book, it opens from the point he left it last time.
I looked up many questions but couldn't get any relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this overlaoding Activity onSaveInstanceState() and call webView.saveState() inside it

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    webView.saveState(outState);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState); 
}
```

Then just call

```
  WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
   if (savedInstanceState != null){
      webview.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }
   else {
      webview.loadUrl(url)
    }
```

in Activity onCreate() method

Comment: Thanks! But it's a bit more complex functionality.
I am using a Webview as a frame to display text. The text is displayed on same activity for every book, so I am getting data from json for every book. And when a user quits reading a book I want to save the reading state for that book not just of the webView, and even after closing the app I want the data to be saved and retrieved again when re-opened. I am thinking to save the current state on a remote server.

Can you tell how can I achieve this.
I want to save the last state of every book and store it on a remote server.